# Stuck on team selection screen

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

While playing CS:GO, I found that for some reason I would get stuck on the pick your team screen.

I could even hear the game going on and it's not like everything froze (I could still move my mouse and it would highlight over the possible choices).

Sometimes it stays like that for nearly an entire game and then randomly drops me on one of the teams.

Has anyone else had this problem and is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened to me a few times. I had to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and restart the game. The problem comes from a connection problem in my opinion. Maybe a ping too high.

Comment: this seems like the most correct answer, i haven't had the problem in a while so it mightve just been a bug they fixed anyways

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that one team was full, and you were trying to join the team in vain? Most likely this is the cause. To help balance things, they restrict players from piling up on one team.

Comment: no this is not the cause at all. i tried clicking both teams and it did not show that either was full

Comment: Check your console.  Always check your console.  For example, if you were joining a jailbreak server, which restricts people on teams, if you went to your console, you could see it would restrict people from joining certain teams.

Comment: do you have to be in game to get to the console? i was stuck on the team choosing screen and it wouldnt even let me spectate

Answer (score 0):

You might try just pressing Spacebar, I believe that will select a random team. If that works, then it's likely the team you were trying to choose was full.

Comment: nah not it.  nothing like that worked