# ALT+F4 doesn't close Counter-Strike: Global Offensive?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> is supposed to work in Counter-Strike GO, as per [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/82590); however, nothing happens when I press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> in the Counter-Strike GO window.

Is there some setting to enable <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, or will I have to code a workaround?

Comment: Hi Anonymous, welcome to the site! I suspect it has something to do with your computer more so than the actual game, could you add a little more info to your question? specifically, what type of computer (Laptop/desktop & brand), does Alt+F4 work elsewhere? (on a browser window, for example)

Comment: Are you using a laptop where you need to press `Fn`?

Comment: I am not using a laptop keyboard. ALT+F4 works correctly in other applications; it just doesn't work in Counter-Strike GO.

Comment: Alt + F4 is blocked in the game, to prevent accidental closing, in case one used it in windowed mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alt-F4 doesn't work for me either and I'm on a normal computer. But I'm not sure if Alt-F4 is supposed to work - CS games for years now used <kbd>F10</kbd> to close the game and this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind some key by console

Example: bind p "exit"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a laptop, you may need to push the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to actually get to the <kbd>F4</kbd> keypress, meaning the combination becomes <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

Or, as other people have said, CS:GO uses <kbd>F10</kbd>, so you may need to push <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

Comment: He mentions that ALT+F4 does work in other applications.

Comment: @Bora He mentioned that after I'd added this answer (check the timestamps)